# What fields are converted by State and Country/Territory Picklist?

Tags: custom-field, country-and-state

I am looking to implement this.
what fields will be changed by this? Only the default ones? Or does this apply to custom fields from custom objects as well?
For example, we have a field called Zuora__BillToCountry__c in a custom object.

Can I apply this to it as well? Will it retain the API name?

I'm guessing this will only apply to fields where field type is "Address", is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature affects only standard address fields on all objects on which they are found, including Account Brands, Accounts, Assets, Contacts, Contracts, Leads, and Orders, as well as any Custom Fields of type [Address](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.fields_caf.htm&type=5) (in Beta, at the time of this answer). All other custom fields will not be affected by enabling this feature.